# UI testing trimmed text of textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, testing

I'm testing a WPF app which has some texboxes. When the screen size is not big enough to show the full textbox text, it is "truncated" with an ellipsis: `ABCDEDF` => `ABC ...`

I want to test this behaviour but cannot get never the value `ABC ...` from any text property, always get `ABCDEF`, any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using now. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've narrowed the window so a textBlock is showing the text "ABC ...". I've access the properties Text and DisplayText but they contain "ABCDEFG".

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft reference:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The TextTrimming property specifies the trimming behavior situation
    /// in case of clipping some textual content caused by overflowing the line's box.
    /// </summary>
    public TextTrimming TextTrimming
    {
        get { return (TextTrimming)GetValue(TextTrimmingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextTrimmingProperty, value); }
    }
```

TextTrimming defines how text is trimmed in a WPF TextBlock.